# Bevy coordinates/translation relative to window size

Tags: bevy

I'm creating a 2d loadscreen for my game. I have a 512x512 logo image that I want to put in the bottom right corner of the screen, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the relation between window size and the coordinate plane is. 0,0 is the center of course, but if i put and item at 500,-500, it's completely off the screen windowed, but where you would expect in fullscreen. How can I take the window dimensions and create a translation that would be in frame?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the width and height of the primary window using the parameter `Query<&Window, With<PrimaryWindow>>`

```rust
fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(spawn_logo)
        .add_startup_system(spawn_camera)
        .run();
}

pub fn spawn_logo(
    mut commands: Commands,
    window_query: Query<&Window, With<PrimaryWindow>>,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
) {
    let window = window_query.get_single().unwrap();

    let width = window.width();
    let height = window.height();
    // Spawn the logo at the bottom right corner of the window
    commands.spawn(SpriteBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(width - width / 4.0, height / 4.0, 0.0),
        texture: asset_server.load("sprites/your_logo.png"),
        ..default()
    });
}

pub fn spawn_camera(mut commands: Commands, window_query: Query<&Window, With<PrimaryWindow>>) {
    let window = window_query.get_single().unwrap();

    // Spawn the camera at the center of the screen
    commands.spawn(Camera2dBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(window.width() / 2.0, window.height() / 2.0, 0.0),
        ..default()
    });
}
```